# FAILED: console keymap

Tags: 16.04, console

Any idea?
How to fix this problem.
Out me every time startup or reboot ??

[image]

Comment: What problem? Please [edit] your question and ask an actual question instead of posting an image. I see at least two (hard to read) "FAILED" warnings. Are those the problem? If so, copy the text into your question so we can search for it and also show the output of running `systemctl status console-setup.service` as the error message tells you to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should run `systemctl status console-setup.service` as per suggestion to have a look at the problem.

You may need to execute

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

or

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

and provide suitable answers to the questions those commands ask to recreate a 'working' configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much. problem governments now do , however, like go to places did I get the following 

"/dev/sda5: clean, 2586001/18923520 files, 2611929/75683328 blocks 
How can governments ???

Comment: I have the same problem. But the dpkg reconfigure commands also generate errors

Answer (score 1):

I used the command: `sudo systemctl enable console-setup`

The next time the system started. There was no red message: "Failed to start console ..."

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/bootup-red-text-failed-to-start-set-console-font-and-keymap-in-debian-9-stretch-xfce-4175608843/), you can try:

```
sudo systemctl restart console-setup.service
```

I had the same problem on Debian Stretch, and this resolved it for me.  The error did not recur on reboot.